Kronecker product structure of matrix
I have a matrix $L$, and its outer product $LL'$ - the dimensions of $L$ do not matter, but we can say, for the sake of the notation, that it is $n \times m$.
I observe that $LL'$ has a Kronecker product structure, i.e. I observe that
$LL'=A \bigotimes B$
for some matrices $A$ and $B$ - I would like to exclude the "trivial" case where either $A$ or $B$ are $1 \times 1$.
My question is: does the fact that $LL'$ have a Kronecker product structure always imply that also $L$ has a Kronecker product structure, i.e. that there exist two matrices $C$ and $D$ such that
$L=C \bigotimes D$,
or (if the above does not hold) that we can at least write
$L=(C \bigotimes D)S$,
where $S$ is some linear mapping?
Any help will be gratefully received.

If $A=1$ and $B = LL^T$, then what you said will be satisfied. Do you want to add restriction that neither matrix is 1 by 1?

correct thank you, I would like a more general statement - edited!

[particular case]
I was not able to prove anything for the general case, but I got some advancements for a particular one.

Let's consider the particular case where $L$ is a column matrix (so $m=1$); $A$ is a square matrix of dimensions $a\times a$; and $B$ is a square matrix of dimensions $b\times b$ (so $n=a\times b$). Moreover, all matrices are real.
We can then divide $L$ in $a$ columns of dimension $b$:
$L = \begin{bmatrix}L^1\\L^2\\\vdots\\L^a\end{bmatrix}$
This results in:
$L\,L' = \begin{bmatrix}L^1\,L^{1'} & L^1\,L^{2'} & \dots & L^1\,L^{a'}\\
L^2\,L^{1'} & L^2\,L^{2'} & \dots & L^2\,L^{a'}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots &\vdots\\
L^a\,L^{1'} & L^a\,L^{2'} & \dots & L^a\,L^{a'}\\
\end{bmatrix}$
For this particular case, if $L\,L' = A\bigotimes B$, then each $L^k\,L^{k'}$ must be proportional to $B$:
$L^1\,L^{1'} = A_{11}\,B$
$L^2\,L^{2'} = A_{22}\,B$
$\vdots$
$L^a\,L^{a'} = A_{aa}\,B$

Which means that $\alpha_1\,L^1\,L^{1'} = \alpha_2\,L^2\,L^{2'} = \dots = \alpha_a\,L^a\,L^{a'}$.
Using these equations, we get that all columns $L^k$ are proportional to any given column:
$L = \begin{bmatrix}L^1 \\ \beta_{12}\,L^1 \\ \vdots \\ \beta_{1a}\,L^1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\\beta_{12}\\\vdots\\\beta_{1a}\end{bmatrix} \bigotimes \begin{bmatrix}L^1\end{bmatrix} = C_1 \bigotimes D_1$
$L = \begin{bmatrix}\beta_{21}\,L^2 \\ L^2 \\ \vdots \\ \beta_{2a}\,L^2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\beta_{21}\\1\\\vdots\\\beta_{2a}\end{bmatrix} \bigotimes \begin{bmatrix}L^2\end{bmatrix} = C_2 \bigotimes D_2$
$\vdots$
$L = \begin{bmatrix}\beta_{a1}\,L^a \\ \beta_{a2}\,L^a \\ \vdots \\ L^a\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\beta_{a1}\\\beta_{a_2}\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix} \bigotimes \begin{bmatrix}L^a\end{bmatrix} = C_a \bigotimes D_a$

We can now verify that any $L^i\,L^{j'}$ with $i\neq j$ is also proportional to $B$, so the equations that were not considered are being satisfied as well.

A counterexample: if $A=I_p$, $B=I_q$, then $LL'=I_{pq}$, and $L$ can be an arbitrary orthogonal matrix, not necessarily with Kronecker structure.
